# калькулятор на java + javaFX. Как и где (метод или класс) ограничить ввод данных с клавиатуры

Tags: javafx

Помогите разобраться. Написал простецкий калькулятор на  java + javaFX. Все приложение здесь  [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/Denis_N/desktop-calculator/src/c2cf6c3afce0b0dfea1f8620417de86ee774446a?at=master). При написании старался реализовать паттерн MVC.

Структура такова: **class Executor** - запуск приложения; **class Controller** - обработка нажатий клавиш , **class Calculator** - выполнение вычислений, **inerface Display**, отдельно реализован пользовательский интерфейс - **ui.fxml**

Вопрос такой - где лучше (ПРАВИЛЬНО) реализовать валидацию вводимых пользователем значений (запретить вводить буквы с клавиатуры) в отдельном классе или в методе? Если в методе, то в каком из перечисленных классов этот метод лучше реализовать (гугл не помог, выдает примеры где все реализовано в классе **Main** и кнопки, и проверка и старт приложения и еще кучу всего). Чисто интуитивно, мне хочется валидацию сделать в отдельном классе, но не хватает скила связать это все дело с полем **display** типа TextField

```
class Controller {
    @FXML
    private TextField display;
    //TODO
}
```

строка ui.fxml

```
<TextField fx:id="display" styleClass="display" ......... >
```

Я понимаю,  что нужен метод с регуляркой, который проверяет (ограничивает) ввод пользователем данных с дальнейшим объявлением экземпляра класса валидации в **Controller**-е, но как этот метод связать с полем **display** ума не приложу.

Или я перемудрил с этим всем делом?

Answer (score 1):

Вах, вах, I did it. 
Все решается на много проще. И решается именно так как мне надо было.
Итак, по порядку.

Для реализации ограничения вводимых пользователем данных с клавиатуры необходимо: написать класс который выполняет эту самую проверку и как говорил  **Yuri_Prime**, этот класс должен расширять класс **TextField**. Привожу мой класс в качестве примера

```
package com.javaFX.calculator.validationOfData;  

import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

    public class CalcWindowTxtFld extends TextField {

        public CalcWindowTxtFld() {
        }

        @Override
        public void replaceText(int start, int end, String text) {
            if (text.matches("[ ]") || text.isEmpty()) {
                super.replaceText(start, end, text);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void replaceSelection(String replacement) {
            super.replaceSelection(replacement);
        }
    }
```

Далее, переходим к фпайлу **fxml** прописываем импорт нашего класса Валидатора, вот так:

```
<?import com.javaFX.calculator.validationOfData.CalcWindowTxtFld ?>
```

И заключительный шаг - меняем тип необходимого поля **TextField** на кастомный, в моем случае **CalcWindowTxtFld**. Должно получиться следующее. Было

```
<TextField fx:id="display" styleClass="display" ......... >
```

стало

```
<CalcWindowTxtFld fx:id="display"  styleClass="display" ......... >
```

Следеует заметить, что в **Controller** нет необходимости изменять тип поля с **TextField** на **CalcWindowTxtFld**. Играясь регулярками можно добиться необходимого результата.

Отдельную благодарность хочу выразить **Yuri_Prime** за помощь и подсказки.

Answer (score 0):

Я когда делал валидацию данных для ограничения вводимых данных, наследовал TextField и в нём переопределял метод replaceText(). Это позволило не только ограничить данные после ввода, но так же ограничить вводимые символы - при правильном regexp нельзя будет ввести буквы там, где нужны только цифры. Так же был написан класс для контроля валидации, объект которого указывался как property. На выходе валидатор давал BooleanProperty, который позволял напрямую блокировать объекты интерфейса. 
Итого: два класса и немного колдовства с property. Как мне кажется, оптимальный вариант.

Код модифицированного TextField выглядит вот так:

```
private final ObjectProperty<ValidationChecker> onValidate = 
new SimpleObjectProperty<>(this, "onValidate", null);
private final ObjectProperty<Predicate<String>> symbolsChecker = 
new SimpleObjectProperty<>(this, "symbolsChecker", null);
private final ObjectProperty<Predicate<String>> textChecker = 
new SimpleObjectProperty<>(this, "textChecker", null);

@Override
public void replaceText(int start, int end, String text){
    if(this.getSymbolsChecker() == null || this.getTextChecker() == null){
        //Если не определеные функции проверки символов или текста
        //вести себя как обычное текстовое поле
        super.replaceText(start, end, text);
        return;
    }
    if(this.getSymbolsChecker().test(text)) {
        //Если введённый текст/символы проходят проверку
        //Добавляем его к уже имеющемуся тексту
        //symbolstChecker ограничивает вводимые символы
        super.replaceText(start, end, text);
    }
    if(this.getTextChecker().test(this.getText())) {
        //Если полный текст поля проходит проверку 
        //Уведомляем валидатор, что всё хорошо
        Platform.runLater(() -> this.getOnValidate().handle(new 
ValidationUpdateEvent(this.getId(), true)));
    }
    else {
        //Иначе, уведомляем о том, что всё плохо и 
        //какой-то контрол стоит заблокировать
        Platform.runLater(() -> this.getOnValidate().handle(new
ValidationUpdateEvent(this.getId(), false)));
    }
}
```

Немного пояснений к коду выше. symbolsChecker и textChecker - объекты, реализующие интерфейс Predicate `<String>`, которые решают, будет ли добавлен введённый текст к текстовому полю(symbolsChecker) и пройдёт ли валидацию весь текст в текстовом поле(textChecker). Две проверки использованы так как в моей задаче нужно было ограничить ввод только на цифры и плюс ограничить диапазон вводимых чисел. Они сделаны через property для того, чтобы можно было указывать их не в коде, а через FXML файл.

Код валидатора крайне прост:

```
public class ValidationChecker implements EventHandler<ValidationUpdateEvent>
private HashMap<String, Boolean> validationInfo = new HashMap<>();
private BooleanProperty isValid = new SimpleBooleanProperty(this, 
"isValid", true);

@Override
public void handle(ValidationUpdateEvent event) {
    this.validationInfo.put(event.getID(), event.isValid());
    if(this.validationInfo.containsValue(false)){
        this.isValid.set(false);
    }
    else{
        this.isValid.set(true);
    }
}
```

Снова немного пояснений. У каждого TextField выставляется текстовое property ID. При попытке ввода данных в текстовое поле, будет оповещён валидатор, который пропишет в HashMap текущее значение валидности поля с указанным ID. 
В этом валидаторе реализовано логическое И: если хоть в одном текстовом поле, связанном с валидатором данные будут не валидны, то свойство isValid будет равно false, а контрол, у которого свойство disable забиндено на isValid валидатора будет заблокирован.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Реализацию вего этого дела я пока смутно представляю, но буду пробовать.

Comment: Если нужно, могу примерно расписать, как у меня это реализовано

Comment: О, буду Вам очень благодарен.

Comment: Обновил ответ, смотрите

Comment: Спасибо Вам, за столь развернутый ответ. Я его завтра постараюсь прикрутить к своеу приложению и отпишусь о результатах.

Comment: Возможно я не вижу элементарных вещей, но интерфейс EventHandler принимает у меня только Event, на ValidationUpdateEvent ругается (возможно он у вас тоже каким то образом реализован - либо в виде класса или интерфейса)

Comment: Прошу прощения. ValidationUpdateEvent наследуется от Event

Comment: Подскажите, а в чем  смысл ValidationUpdateEvent? Это что то вроде заглушки?

Comment: По сути своей это событие, которое уведомляет валидатор об изменении валидности определённого текстового поля. Я второпях забыл написать, что у него внутри булево поле isValid и String sourceID